Convai with Apple Vision Pro in Unity
I am working on the Apple vision pro and want to add Convai with it which is a conventional AI, and it have an pakcage with unity، the problem is whenever I try to open it the camera is black and when I try to play it on the vision pro the button mkust be in the world space. to solve all of this I used all features scene even this one show the bot but when I get near to it nothing is showed and nothing happens.

Please provide more details, such as what is the package? What button are you referring to? Could you also provide images to better illustrate your issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
